# SQL Like is not taking _

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I would like to query only string that contains this exact string `string_`.

I tried this:

```
select * from table where name like "%string_%"
```

and results also include `string-`, but I need only exact `_`.

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: _ is a LIKE wildcard, you need to escape to search for that character.

Comment: Which database server are we talking about?

Comment: u mean "\"? also "%string\_%" doesnt work

Comment: Also, ANSI SQL uses double quotes for identifiers (e.g. column names), use single quotes for string literals.

Comment: mysql ... and ' did the trick :) also with \ thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_` is the wildcard in SQL for a single character. If you want to search for `_` you need to escape it:

```
select * 
from some_table 
where name like '%string\_%' escape '\'
```

---

Additionally: string literals are put into single quotes in SQL. If you ever want to use a more standard compliant DBMS (Oracle, Postgres) you should get used to using single quotes for strings. Double quotes are only for identifiers (and should essentially be avoided in the first place)

Comment: Just a minor note, there's a single quote/double quote inconsistency.

Comment: @jarlh: you are right. I just copied the original statement. I fixed the "invalid" double quotes.

Comment: it works with single quotes... thanks. I tried also \ but there was double quotes problem. Done. Thanks a lot